# WPF (Desired) Size Overview

Tags: wpf, layout

I was wondering if someone found an overview of what certain sizes measure in WPF.

For example, after testing I found out that a control's desired size does not include it's border width and margin. I assume this also holds for actual size and size. Did anybody found (a picture) explaining exactly what is included in the sizes? Are there other parts that contribute to the 'visual size' of the standard controls that I missed?

Of course I could test it for a number of standard controls, but I'd rather not guess these things.

(Context: I'm writing my own layout algorithm, and that's why the actual visual size + borders and margins and anything I missed is important).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did an AutoSizeGrid some months ago that use the [`MeasureOverride`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride.aspx) method.

The big picture is when the window is rendering, it call a first pass to every children to know their desired size. Then is resize everthing on a second pass based on the previous desired sizes. Take a look a the [layout system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx) too.

Comment: Hey Philippe, originally I thought this wasn't going to help (I'm familiar with MeasureOverride). But the link to the layout system eventually pointed me to methods like the following: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.layoutinformation.getlayoutslot.aspx Wwhich work perfectly!